# An anonymous class using mockito (son class use father class)

Tags: mocking

1. my java source code:

**father class:**

```
@Service

public class ProviderBasicDAO {

    @Autowired

    protected JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public List<Long> getNetworkIds(List<EHIPlan> ehiPlans) {
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(ehiPlans)) {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        } 
        return jdbcTemplate.execute(buildSQL(ehiPlans), new CallableStatementCallback<List<Long>>() {

            @Override
            public List<Long> doInCallableStatement(CallableStatement callableStatement)
                    throws SQLException, DataAccessException { 
                ResultSet resultSet = callableStatement.executeQuery();
                List<Long> networkIds = new ArrayList<>();
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    networkIds.add(resultSet.getLong("network_id"));
                }
                return networkIds;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**Son class:**

```
public class ProviderNameDAO extends ProviderBasicDAO {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Value("#[provider.log.to]")
    private int logTo;

    private int apiType = 2;

    public List<Provider> getProvider(ZipRepository coordinate, NameSearchRequest request, List<Long> carrierIds,
            List<EHIPlan> ehiPlans) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        List<Long> networkIds = getNetworkIds(ehiPlans);

        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(ehiPlans) && CollectionUtils.isEmpty(networkIds)) {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }

        return jdbcTemplate.execute(new CallableStatementCreator() {
            @Override
            public CallableStatement createCallableStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                final StringBuffer sqlBuffer = new StringBuffer(
                        "{call pv_mc_infosearch_by_name(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ,? ,?)}");
                CallableStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareCall(sqlBuffer.toString());
                preparedStatement.setInt(1, apiType);
                preparedStatement.setString(2, SecurityUtil.escapeSQLChar(request.getFirstName()));
                preparedStatement.setString(3, SecurityUtil.escapeSQLChar(request.getLastName()));
                preparedStatement.setString(4, SecurityUtil.escapeSQLChar(request.getFacilityName()));
                preparedStatement.setDouble(5, coordinate.getLatitude());
                preparedStatement.setDouble(6, coordinate.getLongitude());
                preparedStatement.setInt(7, request.getRadius());
                preparedStatement.setString(8, StringUtils.join(networkIds,","));
                preparedStatement.setString(9, StandardizerUtils.convertToString(carrierIds));
                preparedStatement.setInt(10, SearchType.getTypeValue(request.getSearchType()));
                preparedStatement.setInt(11, logTo);
                preparedStatement.setString(12, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                return preparedStatement;
            }
        }, new CallableStatementCallback<List<Provider>>() {
            public List<Provider> doInCallableStatement(CallableStatement cs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
                Map<String, Provider> idAndProviderDetailsMap = new HashMap<>();
                boolean isResultSet = cs.execute();
                int rsCount = 0;
                while (isResultSet) {

                    ResultSet childRs = cs.getResultSet();
                    if (rsCount == 0) {
                        parseProvider(childRs,idAndProviderDetailsMap);
                    }
                    if (rsCount == 1) {
                        parseAddress(childRs,idAndProviderDetailsMap);
                    }

                    if (rsCount == 2) {
                        parseSpecialty(childRs,idAndProviderDetailsMap);
                    }

                    if (rsCount == 3) {
                        parseAffiliation(childRs,idAndProviderDetailsMap);
                    }

                    if (rsCount == 4) {
                        parsePhone(idAndProviderDetailsMap, childRs);
                    }

                    if (rsCount == 5) {
                        parseCarrierGroupIdMap(childRs, idAndProviderDetailsMap);
                    }

                    if (rsCount == 6) {
                        parseLanguage(childRs,idAndProviderDetailsMap);
                    }

                    childRs.close();
                    isResultSet = cs.getMoreResults();
                    rsCount++;
                }
                cs.close();
                return new ArrayList<>(idAndProviderDetailsMap.values());
            }

        });

    }

 1. **my test code:**

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({StandardizerUtils.class,StringUtils.class,UUID.class})
public class ProviderNameDAOTest {

    ProviderNameDAO providerNameDAO;
    ProviderBasicDAO providerBasicDAO;
    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    @Before
    public void preTest() {
        providerNameDAO=new ProviderNameDAO();
        providerBasicDAO=new ProviderBasicDAO();
        jdbcTemplate=PowerMockito.mock(JdbcTemplate.class);
        Whitebox.setInternalState(providerNameDAO, "jdbcTemplate", jdbcTemplate);
        providerBasicDAO.jdbcTemplate=jdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Test
    public void testParseAffiliation() {
        String name="hehe";
        long key=1;
        String value="hehe";
        ZipRepository coordinate=new ZipRepository();
        coordinate.setLongitude(20);
        coordinate.setLatitude(10);

        NameSearchRequest request=new NameSearchRequest();
        request.setFirstName(name);
        request.setLastName(name);
        request.setFacilityName(name);
        request.setRadius(20);
        request.setSearchType("physician");

        List<Long> carrierIds=new ArrayList<>();
        carrierIds.add(key);

        List<EHIPlan> ehiPlans=new ArrayList<>();
        EHIPlan ehiPlan=new EHIPlan();
        ehiPlan.setNetwork("haha");
        ehiPlan.setPlanCategory("hehe");
        ehiPlans.add(ehiPlan);

        //networkIds
        {
            CallableStatement callableStatement=PowerMockito.mock(CallableStatement.class);
            PowerMockito.when(jdbcTemplate.execute(Mockito.any(String.class),Mockito.any(CallableStatementCallback.class))).thenAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
                @Override
                public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                    Object[] args=invocation.getArguments();
                    CallableStatementCallback arg = (CallableStatementCallback)args[1];
                    return ((CallableStatementCallback) arg).doInCallableStatement(callableStatement);
                }
            });

            ResultSet resultSet =PowerMockito.mock(ResultSet.class);
            try {
                PowerMockito.when(callableStatement.executeQuery()).thenReturn(resultSet);
                PowerMockito.when(resultSet.next()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false);
                PowerMockito.when(resultSet.getLong(Mockito.any(String.class))).thenReturn(key);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }

        //mian jdbc
        {
            //prarmeter 1
            PowerMockito.mockStatic(StandardizerUtils.class);
            PowerMockito.mockStatic(StringUtils.class);
            PowerMockito.mockStatic(UUID.class);
            Connection connection=PowerMockito.mock(Connection.class);
            CallableStatement preparedStatement=PowerMockito.mock(CallableStatement.class);
            PowerMockito.when(jdbcTemplate.execute(Mockito.any(CallableStatementCreator.class),Mockito.any(CallableStatementCallback.class)))
                    .thenAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
                @Override
                public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                    Object[] args=invocation.getArguments();
                    CallableStatementCreator arg = (CallableStatementCreator)args[0];
                    return arg.createCallableStatement(connection);
                }
            });
            try {
                PowerMockito.when(connection.prepareCall(Mockito.any(String.class))).thenReturn(preparedStatement);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //prarmeter 2
            CallableStatement cs=PowerMockito.mock(CallableStatement.class);
            PowerMockito.when(jdbcTemplate.execute(Mockito.any(CallableStatementCreator.class),Mockito.any(CallableStatementCallback.class)))
               .thenAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
                @Override
                public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                    Object[] args=invocation.getArguments();
                    CallableStatementCallback arg = (CallableStatementCallback)args[1];
                    return arg.doInCallableStatement(cs);
                }
            });
            try {
                String y="N";
                long l=2;
                PowerMockito.when(cs.execute()).thenReturn(true);
                ResultSet childRs=PowerMockito.mock(ResultSet.class);
                PowerMockito.when(cs.getResultSet()).thenReturn(childRs);
                PowerMockito.when(childRs.getString(Mockito.any(String.class))).thenReturn(y);
                PowerMockito.when(childRs.getLong(Mockito.any(String.class))).thenReturn(l);
                PowerMockito.when(cs.getMoreResults()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(true)
                        .thenReturn(true).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //test body
            try {
                List<Provider> result=providerNameDAO.getProvider(coordinate, request, carrierIds, ehiPlans);
                Assert.assertEquals(1, result.size());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
}

**

 1. error informations:

**
org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.MethodNotFoundException: No methods matching the name(s) executeQuery were found in the class hierarchy of class java.lang.Object.
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.getMethods(WhiteboxImpl.java:1720)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.getMethods(WhiteboxImpl.java:1745)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.getBestMethodCandidate(WhiteboxImpl.java:983)
    at org.powermock.core.MockGateway$MockInvocation.findMethodToInvoke(MockGateway.java:317)
    at org.powermock.core.MockGateway$MockInvocation.init(MockGateway.java:356)
    at org.powermock.core.MockGateway$MockInvocation.<init>(MockGateway.java:307)
    at org.powermock.core.MockGateway.doMethodCall(MockGateway.java:142)
    at org.powermock.core.MockGateway.methodCall(MockGateway.java:125)
    at com.ehi.provider.dao.ProviderNameDAOTest.testParseAffiliation(ProviderNameDAOTest.java:93)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:66)

**

 1. question:

**why the father class method not to uesed in son class? and meantime i am not sure my test code is right completely, if you find my error or have a better idea, please point out in here, thank you !!!
```

Comment: I can use others method in ProviderBasicDAO class ,but i do not know why the method of getNetworkIds(List<EHIPlan> ehiPlans) not to used  and list error tips!

Comment: I have solve the question, because of my fault！